# chunk_split() corrupts multibyte characters

Tags: php, string, split, multibyte, delimited

When I use the `chunk_split()` function, it ruins my accented characters and special characters. How can I correct this problem?

Here is my PHP code.

```
if(count($text) > 0) {
    $text = implode(' ', $text);
    echo chunk_split($text, 8, '<br />'); 
}
```

Ruined accent characters.

```
&a
mp; Post
er ÀÁ�
�ÃÄÅ�
�áâã�
�åÒÓ�
�ÕÖØ�
�óôõ�
�øÈÉ�
�Ëéè�
�ëÇç�
�ÍÎÏ�
�íîï�
�ÚÛÜ�
�úûü�
�Ññ
```

Comment: do you have a examples of a "ruined" output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

chunk_split isn't multibyte safe and there isn't a native mb_chunk_split.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php

Here is a function to do that from a commenter in the php docs:

```
<?php

//from Peter from dezzignz.com 05-Apr-2010 11:30 @ php.net

function mbStringToArray ($str) {
    if (empty($str)) return false;
    $len = mb_strlen($str);
    $array = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $array[] = mb_substr($str, $i, 1);
    }
    return $array;
}

function mb_chunk_split($str, $len, $glue) {
    if (empty($str)) return false;
    $array = mbStringToArray ($str);
    $n = 0;
    $new = '';
    foreach ($array as $char) {
        if ($n < $len) $new .= $char;
        elseif ($n == $len) {
            $new .= $glue . $char;
            $n = 0;
        }
        $n++;
    }
    return $new;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try converting the character set before and after as seen here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php#99316

Comment: I used `utf8_decode` before and `utf8_encode` after. Great idea! (+1) ► `$txt=utf8_encode(chunk_split(utf8_decode($name),15,"<br/>"));`.

Answer (score 0):

Regex offers a very succinct and direct replacement for `chunk_split()` when dealing with multibyte characters.

Pattern breakdown:

```
~       #start pattern delimiter
.{8}    #match 8 of any non-newline character
\K      #forget previously matched characters
(?!$)   #not followed by the end of the string
~       #end pattern delimiter
u       #evaluate in multibyte mode
```

Replace with `<br>` but I'll demonstrate with `\n`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Flc25))

```
$str = 'áâãäąăāæåß§śšşçćčźżžýųűů';

var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '~.{8}\K(?!$)~u',
        "\n",
        $str
    )
);
```

Output:

```
'áâãäąăāæ
åß§śšşçć
čźżžýųűů'
```